# Is there any way to install IE 9 on XP SP3?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What technical reason did Microsoft give for no Internet Explorer 9 on Windows XP?](https://superuser.com/questions/258398/what-technical-reason-did-microsoft-give-for-no-internet-explorer-9-on-windows-xp)

Is there any way to install IE 9 on XP SP3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

Unless you count "Install IE9 on Windows 7 or Vista running in VMWare on Windows XP" which is actually not such a far fetched option since Microsoft offers [Virtual Hard Drives](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) for each IE Version (should soon include IE9).

Answer (score 0):

I believe IE 9 is requires Vista SP2 minimum.