# Install IE 6 and IE 9 on XP SP3

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple versions of Internet Explorer on a machine](https://superuser.com/questions/17670/multiple-versions-of-internet-explorer-on-a-machine)

My PC is having IE 6 on XP SP3. I cannot upgrade my PC to Windows 7 now. I need to use both IE 6 and IE 9 on the same PC. How can I do it ?

Comment: This may interest you: [What technical reason did Microsoft give for no Internet Explorer 9 on Windows XP?](http://superuser.com/questions/258398/what-technical-reason-did-microsoft-give-for-no-internet-explorer-9-on-windows-x)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is you can't. IE9 does not run on XP. Apparently, [it uses Direct2D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9) for its rendering, which is only available in Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista with the Platform Update. <sup>As a side note, [Firefox 4+ does the same thing](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=1775755) for its hardware acceleration. The reason FF will still run on XP is they disable hardware accelerated rendering and fall back to other methods. IE9 cannot do this.</sup>

Your only real option is to run a virtual machine and install a newer version of Windows in there, if you are unable to upgrade your current system.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used  [MultipleIE](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE) when testing older browsers on a computer that has IE9. It installs whatever you want, but if you leave it to default it will install everything all the way back to IE1.

It's a good little bit of kit, and from experience this is the closest thing you'll get to running IE6 on your computer without running a virtual machine.